# Можно ли продавать приложение(Google Play/AppStore) использующее ряд сторонних библиотек?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, appstore

Не нашел в интернете достаточно подробной информации, поэтому хочется спросить у людей имеющих коммерческий опыт продажи мобильных приложений. Могу ли я выставить на продажу свое приложение, которое использует много сторонних библиотек, все они поставляются с лицензией Apache 2.0, почитал на вики, что можно, но нужно уведомить авторов библиотек, что я использую их исходные коды.

Comment: Где написано, что нужно уведомить авторов? Нужно оставить Copyright notice, чтобы конечный пользователь его видел. Практически во всех приложениях от google в about есть "лицензии открытого ПО", ну и во многих других приложениях тоже. Но это про Apache. Совсем другое дело GPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...лицензия Apache даёт пользователю право использовать программное обеспечение для любых целей, свободно распространять, изменять, и распространять изменённые копии, за исключением названия.
>
> Единственным условием, накладываемым лицензией Apache, является информирование получателя о факте использования исходного кода.

Выкладывание приложений с библиотеками под этой лицензией можно, единственное нужно уведомить об этом получателя. Apple и Google такие приложения пропускают без проблем

Comment: вы говорите за простое, бесплатное выкладывание или за выкладывание с коммерческой целью?

Comment: @Dandewine и за некоммерческое и за коммерческое.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: @runia, получатель - это не автор, а конечный пользователь

Comment: @runia т.е я должен написать автору библиотеки о том что я ее использую?

Comment: @lsillarionov быстро писал. Не заметил. Исправил. Спасибо!

Comment: @AdamLuisSean нет. Но библиотеку можно использовать в коммерческих и некоммерческих целях. Так же можете посмотреть вот это комментарий https://toster.ru/q/77184 . Тут все четко описано